# Any Best way to call the MVC action method from Hyperlink

Tags: mvc, controller

Currently, we are having a hyperlink tag and the MVC action method is called directly from hyperlink as

`<a href="/api/sitecore/{controller Name}/{action Name}">` **Hyperlink Text**

While hovering on the **hyperlink text** we are able to see the same link in the browser as `/api/sitecore/{controller Name}/{action Name}`.

Is there a way where we can hide the word `Sitecore` while calling the action method. So that while hovering also we will not be able to see it.

Comment: Is this POST action or GET action on click?

Comment: This is on the POST action

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom route pipeline in sitecore and map to route the url link like below

```
public class YourCustomRouteName
{
    public virtual void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "customapi/linkhover", 
            "customapi/linkhover",
            new {
                controller = "YourAssemblyName.YourControllerName, YourAssemblyName",
                action = "YourActionName", 
                id = UrlParameter.Optional 
            }
        );
    }
}
```

```
<pipelines>
    <initialize>
        <processor type="YourAssemblyName.YourCustomRouteName, YourAssemblyName" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
    </initialize>
</pipelines>
```

```
<a href="customapi/linkhover">
```

This way you can achieve to hide the word Sitecore while calling the action method in any link control .

Reference Link [here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/700677)

Comment: Thanks Debal. Will check the link provided by you.